# Null pointer when working with linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers

i cannot figure out why NULL is not printed

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stddef.h"

typedef struct{

    int info;
    struct DEMO1* next;
} DEMO1;

int main()
{
    int temp;
    DEMO1 *head ;
    if(head==NULL)
    printf("NULL");
}
```

Comment: Head is uninitialised.

Comment: Downvote magnet detected: `System.ALLCAPSEXCEPTION`

Comment: @H2CO3 I take offense at your usage of a Java System constant to describe a question about the C language...

Comment: @io10, you're free to think so, but you're wrong.

Comment: I read it in book . why i am wrong ?

Comment: If you had declared `head` outside of any function, or had put the keyword `static` in front of it, then your assumption that it would be initialized to 0/NULL would have been correct. That default is not true for stack variables, mainly in the name of efficiency (unlike static variables, that possibly unneeded initialization would have to be done every single time the function was entered).

Comment: @RonBurk: And we simply cannot afford the 500 *trillionths* of a second that would take!  :-)

Comment: You jest, but of course there is no limit on how high the overhead *could* be, since some functions may be called *trillions* of times. And I may be writing embedded code for a device that has very little memory, making the space overhead the issue. If you don't need a language that can serve a vast array of such constraints, there are many others to choose from. :-)

Comment: @RonBurk Or you can just use an optimizing compiler, for reality's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory is not initialized upon allocation. You cannot expect it to have a particular value until you set it.

Comment: I thought that upon declaration it holds null value

Comment: Nope. I don't know what else to say... that's just not the case. It holds random data.

Comment: what i am supposed to do ?

Comment: Set it to `NULL` when you create it! `head = NULL;`

Comment: The initial value depends, among other things, on the storage class. Something that is at the top level of a compilation unit will be zero-initialized, but something that is declared in local scope in a function will not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you haven't initialized the head pointer to any value.. It just contains whatever bytes were stored there previously (unless the OS was nice and did some clean up).  You need to initialize head to `NULL` if you would like that if-statement to evaluate to true:

```
int main()
{
    DEMO1 *head = NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
        printf("NULL");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The real life lesson here is that your compiler probably had the ability to inform you that `head` was used before it was initialized. If you did not see such a message, then either you have a fairly poor compiler, or you have not asked the compiler to warn you about all possible problems. Find out how to get all the help your compiler is capable of offering and you could save a lot of time in your programming.

Comment: Do you really think he/she would notice a compiler warning?

Comment: hence he must not give this suggestion that turns out to be useful?

Comment: I compiled the code using codeblocks IDE , there were no warnings and i did not turn off warnings